# Misaligned Ordered List Items in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, alignment, html-lists, items

Has anyone noticed that alpha ordered list items in certain fonts don't line up properly in Chrome?

Example:

```css
li 
{ 
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  list-style: upper-alpha;    
}
ol:after
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 2.45em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<ol>
   <li>Testing</li>
   <li>Testing</li>
   <li>Testing</li>
   <li>Testing</li>
   <li>Testing</li>
   <li>Testing</li>
   <li>Testing</li>
</ol>
```

The periods for items C, D and G are 1 pixel further to the left than the rest of the items.

Here's what I see in Chrome on Windows in case it's somehow limited to certain OS/browser/font versions:

[image: Misaligned item example]

Everything lines up fine in Firefox and IE. I have seen the problem in Chrome on Mac, Windows and Android. It does seem to depend on the font. Most serif fonts that I checked have a problem. Both lower and upper-alpha have the problem, but different items end up shifted by 1 pixel.

Any thoughts on how to fix this, or is this a bug that I just have to wait for Google to fix? I've done some searching, but can't find anyone else mentioning this issue.

Comment: Probably this is just one of those tiny browser differences that can't be controlled. FWIW, your snippet displays correctly (no pixel misalignment) on my Chrome for MacOS.

Comment: Yeah, my assumption was that it's a Chrome bug. Hopefully they fix it soon. I just tried Chrome on Android and it had the same issue. I haven't found a version of Chrome that displays correctly. I'm wondering if your Chrome is a newer or older version than mine. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisting this unanswered question 3 years later... I just tried the example code snippet again and everything's aligned perfectly in Chrome now, so it appears this was probably just a bug that has since been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems still to be an issue in Chrome Version 114.0.5735.133 (Official Build)?

Ordered list list-style-type:upper-alpha[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QGRZ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).